# rpl error "TypeError: encode() argument 1 must be str, not None"

Tags: debian

Maybe I should use a different tool, but rpl has always worked for me like this...

```
rpl -Ris "oldname.com" "newname.com" *
```

(If you're wondering, R = recursive, i = ignore case, s = dry-run simulation)

The error is...

```
The files listed below would be modified in a replace operation.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rpl", line 314, in <module>
main()
  File "/usr/bin/rpl", line 246, in main
matches = blockrepl(f, o, regex, old_str, new_str, 1024)
  File "/usr/bin/rpl", line 92, in blockrepl
parts = (after.join(parts)).encode(encoding=encoding, errors='ignore')
TypeError: encode() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

Answer (score 2):

locale library isn't able to find the default locale and hence failing. The issue can be fixed by setting the `LANG` environment variable to set the default locale like `export LANG=en_US.utf-8`.

Comment: I just ran into the issue in OP on a Docker container of Ubuntu 18.04, and verified the solution in this answer works.